# Minimum supported Gradle version is 4.6

Tags: android, gradle

I want to migrate to Android X, but AS says I should update android.tools.build:gradle: to version 3.2.0. After the update I received an error. **The minimum supported version of Gradle is 4.6. The current version is 4.4 Please correct the Gradle settings of the project.**

But I have gradle-4.10 now.

What can be wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I have been developing on android studio preview version and below configation working for my android studio
change following files

> Project level build.gradle

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0-alpha03'
```

> gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.0-milestone-1-all.zip
```

and add below two line as per https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

> gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```